Does "engage" mean "obtain" when referring to inanimate or abstract things?
One of the definitions for the word "enlist" by Oxford Learners Dictionary is:
enlist:
engage (a person or their help or support).
"the company enlisted the help of independent consultants"
syn: obtain; engage; win; get; procure; (Oxford Learners Dictionary)
I don't understand why engage is used here. AFAIK "* *" applies to humans and means "hire" in those contexts. Does "engage" mean "obtain" and "get" like the synonyms below when talking about help or support (like in definition)? I can't find any evidence to confirm that.
(Would you say "I engaged his support before the election?")
engage:

To obtain or contract for the services of; employ: engage a carpenter.(American Heritage® Dictionary)


The answer is right there and it is not hire. The dictionary definition could not be clearer.

What is "here"?   Are you asking whether engage is a valid synonym for enlist?

It says that obtain and get are synonyms of enlist, not of engage (and enlist basically means 'put on a list' (of members or supporters)).

Let's say there is a hypothetical situation in which I'm supposed to do a chore for my mom. Can I say e.g to my friend "I'm going to enlist/engage help of my sister on this one. She owes me a favour"?

You could say "I'm going to enlist/engage the help of my sister on this one. She owes me a favour." But it would be ridiculously formal. It might be used in business.

@Stuart F Thank you Stuart F. That's the type of answer I'm always on the lookout for. Not only will this make me sound formal but also more intelligent than I really am, which is what I'm aiming for :)

I have  seen enlist used mainly in the context of volunteer assistance and engage used in the context of professional (paid) assistance.

The publisher engaged the services of a professional translator.
The gardening club  enlisted  members of the local high school football team to plant the larger saplings  in the park next to the library.

But I imagine you could find examples somewhere of  enlist in paid contexts and engage in volunteer contexts.
One could define engage as "to make the necessary arrangements to procure a service".  It is a transitive verb and can take an abstraction as its direct object (e.g. "the services") or the person or entity providing such services:

The publisher engaged a professional translator.
The company engaged a consultancy to help them open a subsidiary overseas.


Military service personnel are enlisted and they get paid.

@DaleM   Not the same construction.  Military personnel are enllsited because they have enlisted, not because they were enlisted.
